# How to select 1 row when joining table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

My goal is to get Users and ONE latest entry user has created, I've tried to figure it out on google but I failed, so you're my last chance. On of things I tried:

```
        DB::select('SELECT u.id, u.username, u.user_rating, 
                        u.avatar, u.created_at, e.id as e_id, e.title 
                        FROM users u
                        LEFT JOIN 
                        (
                            SELECT e.*
                            FROM entry e
                            LIMIT 1
                        ) entry AS e ON e.user_id = u.id
                        ORDER BY u.user_rating DESC 
                        LIMIT 10
```

I'm using MySQL

**EDIT:**

with this it don't give me error, but it doesnt take any entry from join:

```
DB::select('SELECT u.id, u.username, u.user_rating, 
          u.avatar, u.created_at, e.id as e_id, e.title 
           FROM users u
           LEFT JOIN 
           (
               SELECT e.*
               FROM entry e
               ORDER BY e.id DESC
               LIMIT 1
           ) AS e ON e.user_id = u.id
            ORDER BY u.user_rating DESC 
            LIMIT 10');
```

The result:

```
object(stdClass)#437 (7) {
["id"]=>
int(5002)
["username"]=>
string(6) "Nelosh"
["user_rating"]=>
int(77763)
["avatar"]=>
string(3) "its"
["created_at"]=>
string(19) "2013-12-16 19:20:23"
["e_id"]=>
NULL
["title"]=>
NULL
```

}

Comment: so you want to get ALL users and for EACH user the one latest entry ?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: I've edited, Dwza - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.user_rating, u.avatar, u.created_at, e.id AS e_id, e.title 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM entry e ORDER BY e.user_id, e.id DESC) AS e GROUP BY e.user_id) AS e ON e.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY u.user_rating DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.user_rating, u.avatar, u.created_at, e.id AS e_id, e.title 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM entry e ORDER BY e.user_id, e.id DESC) AS e ON e.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.user_rating DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

**EDIT:::**

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.user_rating, u.avatar, u.created_at, e.id AS e_id, e.title 
FROM (SELECT u.id, u.username, u.user_rating, u.avatar, u.created_at FROM users u ORDER BY u.user_rating DESC LIMIT 10) AS u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT e.id, e.user_id, e.title FROM entry e ORDER BY e.user_id, e.id DESC) AS e ON e.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: Your solution is not working, because it can't load.

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis What is the problem can u explain?

Comment: Execution more than 30 sec

Comment: Same, execution more than 30 sec :( Is it really possible to limit 1 row in joins?

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis If you use limit 1 then you will get only last record of 1 user, you can't fetch latest entry of each user using LIMIT 1. If you want to fetch all the data of each user then you can't use LIMIT 1

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis Try my last updated query and if query takes longer than go for proper INDEXING on your table. And check all three queries and use whichever is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 DB::select('SELECT u.id, u.username, u.user_rating, 
              u.avatar, u.created_at, e.id as e_id, e.title 
               FROM users u
               LEFT JOIN 
               (
                   SELECT e.*
                   FROM entry e
                   ORDER BY e.created_date DESC //add this condition also
                   LIMIT 1
               ) entry AS e ON e.user_id = u.id
                ORDER BY u.user_rating DESC 
                LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS p ON p.user_id = u.id ORDER BY u.user_rating DESC '

Comment: in original is, I just renamed it here

Answer (score 0):

In your subquery you need to add ORDER BY to get the last entry. If your e.id is autoincremented, you can do this:

```
...
SELECT e.*
FROM entry e
ORDER BY e.id DESC LIMIT 1
...
```